# Only allowed to add 2 days on date picker but exclude Saturday and Sundays

Tags: jquery, datepicker

For example if my set date is September 2, 2019 (Monday), my only options is Sept 3 and 4. But if my set date is September 6 (Friday), my options must skip 7 8 and only allow me to pick Sept 9 and 10.

I have the following code now, but I'm not able to make the setDate work so I don't know if noWeekEnds will work on maxDate automatically:

```
$( "#release_date").datepicker({
     setDate: new Date('2019-09-05'),
     yearRange:"c-100:c+0",
     minDate:'0',
     maxDate: '+2d',
     beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

Comment: what datepicker plugin are you using, can you provide a mvp code example with what you are trying to achieve?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I explained what I'm trying to achieve on the first paragraph. I'm using jQuery Datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: 1,
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,// magic happens here
    maxDate: 4 // change it to your requirements
});
```